# Send and Receive SMS from PHP Application

Tags: php, api, sms

I want to make a Facebook like SMS sending and receiving service. Are there any PHP API to do that? I want to use a specific number like Facebook.

**Note**
Sending SMS through E-mail is possible but how can I receive SMSs through my PHP application? I am searching for a free PHP API without any external hardware to do that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case your search for free doesn't work out:

I've recently been playing around with Twilio: http://www.twilio.com/

And they've recently cleaned up their API:

http://blog.twilio.com/2010/08/announcing-the-new-twilio-api-version-2010-04-01.html

They also have contests running. Maybe your app will fall into a category and land some free marketing :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work in India, use [smsgupshup.com](http://api.smsgupshup.com/app_help/what_is_app)'s API to create SMS applications.

Comment: smsgupshup.com is good. But I want to use my own number instead of 56767888 and use a application like smsgupshup.com

Comment: If you want to use your own number then you have to opt for SIM hosting somewhere or use your own hardware. (You can connect a phone USB to a serial port of computer.)

Answer (score 0):

This software will let you receive sms in PHP: [Receive SMS](http://smsenabler.com)

It connects to a 3G/GSM modem or dongle and will automatically post incoming SMS messages to your website where you can handle them using a simple PHP script