# How to receive the mobile sms to a server using php

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

Can any one explain how to achieve the below requirement.

1. Say user sends a message like eg: TDFEED Nice work ! to some common no like 5858.
2. I need to receive this text message to my server.
3. Manipulate the text and in reply i need to send an acknowledgement.

I need how to achieve this using php or any other language.

Thanks,
Lokesh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send and Receive SMS from PHP Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655740/send-and-receive-sms-from-php-application)

Answer (score 5):

Use Twilio (http://www.twilio.com/), I'm using them now to send SMS messages and their API for receiving them is very simple and easy to setup.

Docs: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/sms/hello-monkey

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SMS software [http://smsenabler.com](http://smsenabler.com/). It can automatically post incoming SMS messages to the URL of your PHP script and send back reply SMS messages.

It uses a 3G/GSM modem (dongle) plugged in a computer to receive SMS. Such modems/dongles have a SIM card inside, therefore they have a phone number to which text messages can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [www.aql.com](http://www.aql.com) to receive SMS messages into your application. May work best in the UK...