# Want to send SMS and get results from database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sms, sms-gateway

I got an project where I have to create a system like "I will send SMS to a server page in PHP and in return I will get results as SMS from the database". I am familiar with PHP and MySQL, but have no idea how to implement it with SMS system.

Comment: I'm no expert but I'd use an arduino with GPSM/GSM. Main reason because you can communicate with an arduino using an ethernet cable. This might not be what you're looking for but it may help.
 http://labs.arduino.cc/GPRS/Index

Comment: You need to buy some SMS gateway and integrate in your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send and Receive SMS from PHP Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655740/send-and-receive-sms-from-php-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*

Really, your best bet will be an API that provides sending/receiving SMS. Generally speaking, they all allow you to send an SMS using a HTTP request, and incoming SMS result in a GET/POST (similar to a regular form submission) to a URL you specify.

Here are a few of the bigger SMS APIs:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its of great help